# Change data in the database after indicated time

Tags: laravel

In a certain amount of time after the user clicks a button, I need to have some data in the database changed.

For example, there is a `sessions` table with the `is_active`(default value `0`) field and two buttons.  After the first button clicked the field has to be equal `1` for 5 minutes; after clicking the second button field has to be equal `0` immediately.

In the first place, I thought Queues or Task Scheduling might be the solution, but I don't see how make it works

Is that even possible to do by Laravel?

Comment: try `setTimeout` in javascript.

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran I need it happened even if the browser will be closed

Comment: Another solution would be to replace your is_active column with a last_activity column which would be the date when the user clicked the first button.
When the user clicks the second button, you can set the value to null. A null value or a date older than 5 minutes would be considered as false.

Comment: @Alex83690 Thanks for the hint, but it is too late to make that changes (

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can with some help of the database. You can define a schedule that runs once in a moment, and you can push a record to the database when an user clicks a button. Then on the scheduled task, check if there are any tasks need to be run in that moment, or past moments etc. Then delete the task when it's done from the database. Be aware that on the next query, if there are jobs still running, add an extra flag to the table saying that the job has started, and don't run that again.